# After I upgraded to macOS Ventura (13.0) nextjs and any npx command stuck

Tags: npm, web, next.js, oh-my-zsh, npx

After I upgraded to macOS 13. I found a problem with command in nextjs first. I tried to run my project with: `npm run dev`

This is result:

```
> dev
> next dev
```

It stucked on this log very very long time.

and I tried to create another project using:

`npx create-next-app@latest`

Result same to nextjs

About my computer:

- Macbook pro 2018 13-inch 4 ports
- I used Oh My Zsh on terminal
- my node.js version is 16.18.0 (16.9.1 on this question created)

**UPDATED 27/10/22**

After I asked in this community. I tried many way to solve this issues.
This is way I tried:

- Reinstall macOS Ventura and not working
- Change node.js version to 16.18.0 => 19.0.0 and downgraded to 16.18.0 and not working

And now this problem is still. I still can't resolve this problem :(

Comment: node.js 16.9.1 is pretty old, maybe it contains bugs that were fixed in later versions?

Comment: I updated to 16.18.0 and it's not working.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Updated 28/10/2022** This problem I can resolved!!!!!

Today, I tried to clean install macOS Ventura (by backup internal storage => erase internal storage => install macOS Ventura by bootable drive and recovery data from backup hard disk)

All commands worked normally!

If you found a problem like this, you can resolve by clean install macOS!

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there anyway to fix it without reinstalling the OS?

Comment: I have tried every possible way. There is no way but to clean installing macos

Comment: I have solved it by updating npm.

Comment: Correction: seemed to have been only a temporary fix. Yesterday everything was fine today it stopped working (npm install freezes). What a mess...

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem when I tried to run the nestjs application. Also failed to install packages, I got this error every time
[image]
It turned out that this could be a problem related to the IPv6 configuration. I disabled this setting and everything started working fine
[image]

Maybe it will also help you.

UPDATES
You can find this settings
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where can I find this setting?